# Is it appropriate to include Cydia tweak projects in resume?

Tags: resume

I'm a graduate student who is looking for a full-time job in software engineering.

I have built a small Cydia tweak(location spoofer) for jailbroken iOS devices. Is it appropriate to include that in my resume?

Moreover, does it have negative impact if I'm interviewing with Apple?

Comment: I believe this may into the category of duplicating [This Question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14252/should-one-reference-potentially-illegal-activities-on-their-cv). While the legality is for someone else to decide a company may view it this way.

Answer (score 3):

What you put on your resume depends almost ***entirely*** on the kind of job you are seeking, and the kind of company you are applying to.

If you were to apply for a software engineering position at my company, including this project would be useless at the best, and harmful at the worst. We are a business in the financial services industry that doesn't deal with iOS devices, and has high security standards. I suspect any project with the words "jailbreak" or "spoof" in it wouldn't be highly regarded here.

On the other hand, if you were applying for a software engineering position at a mobile security firm, including such a project would likely be highly desirable.

Comment: Maybe instead of using the phrase "location spoof" the OP could say "allow users to customize their devices location setting" (or something like that), and give at least one example of a legitimate use of this.

Comment: Joe, you ought to consider that if you are afraid of developers who understand security enough to do a legal security related utility then really you are decreasing the security of your products.

Answer (score 2):

Having a personal project like that is a big plus if you interview with the small companies that I've worked at for the last 19 years.

Big companies looking for 'organization men' might be different, I wouldn't know.

I'll turn the question around:  Would you prefer to work at:

1) A company that sees the value in a project like yours? A security minded company who understands the value of a white-hat?

or

2) A company that freaks out because you used words commonly used by the people who actually write code?

Take your pick.